# CNN - Model predicting all the same class

Tags: networking, theano, convolution, keras

I have read some of the other answers to a similar problem on stackoverflow, however I have found nothing to help me in this case. I have a set of 539 RGB images, dimensions 607 x 607 x 3, and each image is one of 6 classes. I have had success with the MNIST and CIFAR10 datasets, however when I create CNNs for this dataset, the test val_acc produced when training is remaining constant / produced by predicting all the same classes (which may vary). Below I have included my code and an example CNN, as well as the output on the GPU:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import cPickle
import gzip
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop
from keras.utils import np_utils, generic_utils
from theano.tensor.nnet import conv
from theano.tensor.nnet import softmax
from theano.tensor import shared_randomstreams
from theano.tensor.signal import downsample
from theano.tensor.nnet import sigmoid
from theano.tensor import tanh
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import os, struct
from array import array as pyarray
from numpy import append, array, int8, uint8, zeros,genfromtxt, matrix
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from random import randint
import cv2

# Setting up the Data
A=539; 
l = float(genfromtxt("/home/silo1/ad2512/Histo_6/L" + str(1) + ".csv",delimiter=','))
l1 = float(genfromtxt("/home/silo1/ad2512/Histo_6/L" + str(2) + ".csv",delimiter=','))
d = cv2.imread('/home/silo1/ad2512/Histo_6/SI1.jpg')
d1 = cv2.imread('/home/silo1/ad2512/Histo_6/SI2.jpg')
all_data=[d,d1]
labels=[l,l1]
for i in range(A-2):
    if((i+3)>A):
        break
    l = float(genfromtxt("/home/silo1/ad2512/Histo_6/L" + str(i+3) + ".csv",delimiter=','))
    d = cv2.imread("/home/silo1/ad2512/Histo_6/SI" + str(i+3) + ".jpg")
    all_data.append(d)
    labels.append(l)

s = np.shape(all_data)[1]
all_data = np.asarray(all_data) 
all_data = all_data.astype('float32')
all_data = all_data.reshape(A,3,s,s)
labels = np.asarray(labels)
labels = labels.astype('int')
labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels)


# Building Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,init='uniform',border_mode='full',input_shape=(3,s,s)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='full'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(500))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(500))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(6))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="RMSprop")
model.fit(all_data[0:200], labels[0:200], batch_size=10, nb_epoch=15,verbose=1,show_accuracy=True,validation_data=(all_data[400:539], labels[400:539]))
```

And the output for the first 9 epochs:

```
Epoch 1/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 2.6849 - acc: 0.2500 - val_loss: 1.6781 - val_acc: 0.3957
Epoch 2/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 2.0138 - acc: 0.1800 - val_loss: 2.1653 - val_acc: 0.2518
Epoch 3/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 1.8683 - acc: 0.2600 - val_loss: 1.7330 - val_acc: 0.2518
Epoch 4/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 1.8136 - acc: 0.2200 - val_loss: 2.1307 - val_acc: 0.1871
Epoch 5/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 1.7284 - acc: 0.2600 - val_loss: 1.6952 - val_acc: 0.2518
Epoch 6/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 1.7373 - acc: 0.2900 - val_loss: 1.6020 - val_acc: 0.2518
Epoch 7/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 1.6809 - acc: 0.3050 - val_loss: 1.6524 - val_acc: 0.2518
Epoch 8/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 1.7306 - acc: 0.3350 - val_loss: 1.7867 - val_acc: 0.1871
Epoch 9/15
200/200 [==============================] - 73s - loss: 1.7803 - acc: 0.2400 - val_loss: 1.8107 - val_acc: 0.2518
```

I have tried changing the number of nodes in the hidden layer, creating more complicated models, changing activation functions, everything I can think of. If I were to run the CIFAR10 dataset through this (and change the last layer to Dense(10) rather than Dense(6)) I get successful results - Not sure if there is a problem with the data I am importing, however the np.shape structure for my data is exactly the same as the np.shape structure for the CIFAR10 dataset

Answer (score 0):

val_acc is not constant, it's jumping back and forth. Try lowering the learning rate 10 times then 10 times again until it starts learning. You will have to create an RMSProp object and pass the object in instead of a string.

Comment: It is either constant, or jumping between predictions of all the same classes - notice how it is jumping between the same values - this is the accuracy of predicting all of one class, compared to predicting all of another class. Will look at the RMSProp object now, however I tried with sgd using a much lower learning rate and still no success

Comment: I ran the suggestion with learning rate at 1e-4, 1e-5 and 1e-6 and this as not fixed the problem.